# Raspbian taskbar autohide menu stays but the panel disappears

Tags: raspbian, taskbar

i was playing around with `Raspbian\raspberrypi os` the other day, I turned on the `the Minimize panel when not in use` for my taskbar. But the problem is when i press on the start button and keep my cursor on the menu the taskbar disappears is there a way to prevent this form happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't something that can be done in a config file. Looking at the source code for lxpanel I found the logic behind the autohide feature.

Location of message in github repository: `/src/panel.c`

```
/****************************************************
 *         autohide : borrowed from fbpanel         *
 ****************************************************/

/* Autohide is behaviour when panel hides itself when mouse is "far enough"
 * and pops up again when mouse comes "close enough".
 * Formally, it's a state machine with 3 states that driven by mouse
 * coordinates and timer:
 * 1. VISIBLE - ensures that panel is visible. When/if mouse goes "far enough"
 *      switches to WAITING state
 * 2. WAITING - starts timer. If mouse comes "close enough", stops timer and
 *      switches to VISIBLE.  If timer expires, switches to HIDDEN
 * 3. HIDDEN - hides panel. When mouse comes "close enough" switches to VISIBLE
 *
 * Note 1
 * Mouse coordinates are queried every PERIOD milisec
 *
 * Note 2
 * If mouse is less then GAP pixels to panel it's considered to be close,
 * otherwise it's far
 */
```

So, it looks like you would have to change the source code of lxpanel with your own **custom** autohide logic.

That logic might look an additional check to see if your mouse cursor is within the coordinates of the start menu. That way the program knows that you are trying to use the start menu. But, this logic would also force lxpanel to show up if you move the mouse cursor into the area of the start menu without the menu being there.

Comment: Do you know how to write a custom autohide logic? is there any documentation on it?
And thx for your awnser!

Comment: You would modify the /src/panel.c file and then compile your own version of lxpanel. You can check out the lxpanel github page. It contains a little bit of information on how to build your own version. https://github.com/lxde/lxpanel

Comment: @PyCoder64 The documentation on how to write a feature in C would be a book on programming, and the GTK2 [reference](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk2/stable/).

Comment: Thx all who contributed to this little project!